# How do I get my PHP form redirect to work?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've created a form with the following html and php code, and basically it runs a check to see if the spam question has been completed successfully in which case it should process the form, send an email through and redirect the user to the thankyou.html page. However at the moment, on success, the form just reloads the same page and doesn't redirect to the thank you page, however I do receive a confirmation email...

Is there something I've missed off/got wrong in the code below to stop this from actioning?

```
<form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="name">Name:<span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span></label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="email">Email:<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span></label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="telephone">Telephone:<span class="error"><?php echo $telErr;?></span></label></td>
            <td><input name="telephone" type="text" id="telephone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="field">Anti-spam question:<span class="error"><?php echo $spamErr;?></span></label></td>
            <td><input name="field" type="text" id="field" value="Complete the Beatles lyric: all you need is...?"  onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"  onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Complete the Beatles lyric: all you need is...?';}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="message">Message:</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="message"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><img src="images/contactdots.gif" width="338" height="10" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><input id="button" type="Submit" value="SUBMIT" alt="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

// Pick up the form data and assign it to variables
$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$tel = $_POST['telephone'];
$comments = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
$field = strtolower($_POST['field']);
$spam_check = 'love';
if($field == $spam_check){
// Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
$to = 'my@email.com';
$subject = "The Vintage Affair Web Quote enquiry";
$comments = "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nTelephone: $tel \n\nDetails: $comments";
$headers = "From: my@email.com" . PHP_EOL . "Reply-To: my@email.com";

// Send the mail using PHPs mail() function
mail($to, $subject, $comments, $headers);

// Redirect
header("Location: thankyou.html");
}
else{ echo '<div class="spam">*You got the Beatle\'s lyric wrong, please try again*</div>'; }
}

?>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to put the `header()` call *before* any output.  Or use output buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're outputting data before calling the header(), it won't work like this.

Put all the PHP above the form.

Comment: Excellent...that worked! Thank you for your quick response too.

Comment: No problem, for future reference it's sometimes unavoidable to have output before the header(), in this case you can use ob_start() / ob_end_flush() to buffer your output, you can read more about ouput control here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 1):

`header()` must be sent before ANY output, should it be a space or a string.

You must check the form submission before, like this:

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['myform'] )
{
 if( spam_check($_POST['myform']) === true )
 {
   header("Location: thankyou.html");
 }
 else 
 { 
  echo '<div class="spam">*You got the Beatle\'s lyric wrong, please try again*</div>';
 }
}
else
{
  display_form();
}
?>
```

Being dispay_form() a function that displays all the HTML, maybe with a `file_get_contents()` of a HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem and I've found this solution :

```
if (!headers_sent()){
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
}
else {
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'window.location.href="thankyou.html";';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=thankyou.html" />';
    echo '</noscript>';
}
```

I hope that it Will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
header("Location: thankyou.html");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your problem is that you actually output stuff on the screen before you run your checks.
Headers are sent right before any output in your case the **HTML** code.

Use **ob_start();**  **ob_end_flush();** pair at the beginning of the file something like

```
<?php 
   ob_start(); // this stores the output in a buffer for later use
?>

html code here

<?php



if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    // Pick up the form data and assign it to variables
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $tel = $_POST['telephone'];
    $comments = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
    $field = strtolower($_POST['field']);
    $spam_check = 'love';

    if($field == $spam_check){
        // Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
        $to = 'my@email.com';
        $subject = "The Vintage Affair Web Quote enquiry";
        $comments = "Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nTelephone: $tel \n\nDetails: $comments";
        $headers = "From: my@email.com" . PHP_EOL . "Reply-To: my@email.com";

        // Send the mail using PHPs mail() function
        mail($to, $subject, $comments, $headers);

        // Redirect
        header("Location: thankyou.html");
   }
    else echo '<div class="spam">*You got the Beatle\'s lyric wrong, please try again*</div>';
}

ob_end_flush(); // this is for printing the buffered output
?>
```

**ob_end_flush();** at the end

Answer (score 0):

Put the form below the php codes